# How can I create two time values (currentHour and currentMinute) from a TimePicker then concatenate them together

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I have two values in my source code timeEt (I'll rename this later to hourEt) and minEt and I'd like to combine them together into a string I can display in an xml layout - I've been able to compile the code below but I'm getting stuck and I need some help all I want to do is add a little bit of code to combine the currentHour and currentMinute into one string so I can call the time from the TimePicker in an xml layout later)

AddEditCountry.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;
     private TimePicker minEt;
     public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
     public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
       //   minEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.minEdit);


          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) ? extras.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) : 0);
             minEt.setCurrentMinute(extras.getInt("min"));
          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }


           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                          minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
              else
              {
                 dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                    nameEt.getText().toString(),
                    capEt.getText().toString(),
                    timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString(),
                    minEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),/* Storing as String*/
                    codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
           }
}
```

Updated Database Connector (.java) w Bill Motes helpful suggestions

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



public class DatabaseConnector {

    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
    public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";
    private static final String DB_NAME = "WorldCountries";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;

    public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    }

       public void open() throws SQLException 
       {
          //open database in reading/writing mode
          database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       } 

       public void close() 
       {
          if (database != null)
             database.close();
       }       

       public void insertContact(String name, String cap, String code, String time, String min) 
               {
                  ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
                  newCon.put("name", name);
                  newCon.put("cap", cap);
                  newCon.put("time", time);
                  newCon.put("min", min);
                  newCon.put("code", code);
                  newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
                  newCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);

                  open();
                  database.insert("country", null, newCon);
                  close();
               }


               public void updateContact(long id, String name, String cap,String code, String time, String min) 
               {
                  ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
                  editCon.put("name", name);
                  editCon.put("cap", cap);
                  editCon.put("time", time);
                  editCon.put("min", min);
                  editCon.put("code", code);
                  editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, time);
                  editCon.put(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, min);
                  open();
                  database.update("country", editCon, "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }


               public Cursor getAllContacts() 
               {
                  return database.query("country", new String[] {"_id", "name"}, 
                     null, null, null, null, "name");
               }

               public Cursor getOneContact(long id) 
               {
                  return database.query("country", null, "_id=" + id, null, null, null, null);
               }

               public void deleteContact(long id) 
               {
                  open(); 
                  database.delete("country", "_id=" + id, null);
                  close();
               }
}
```

After adding Bill Mote's helpful suggestions it's still crashing. I've updated the logcat below and the source code above. I feel I'm much closer to integrating a single string which calls the combined currentHour and currentMinute buttons from the TimePicker - but I'm still stuck (any input from any StackOverflow members is MORE than welcome!)

LOGCAT:

```
03-24 00:48:57.779: D/Activity(6809): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-24 00:48:57.959: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(6809): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-24 00:48:57.959: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5ca41000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:54
03-24 00:48:58.049: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dc22000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:75
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dcb8000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:78
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d4ce000 size:614400
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5d6f7000 size:614400
03-24 00:48:58.079: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5c929000 size:614400
03-24 00:49:10.623: W/dalvikvm(6809): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410889d8)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry.saveContact(AddEditCountry.java:101)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry.access$1(AddEditCountry.java:92)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at com.nfc.linkingmanager.AddEditCountry$1$1.doInBackground(AddEditCountry.java:65)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-24 00:49:10.643: E/AndroidRuntime(6809):     ... 5 more
03-24 00:49:10.663: D/Activity(6809): Activity.onPause(), editTextTapSensorList size: 0
03-24 00:49:10.693: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(6809): <ConfigWindowMatch:2165>: Format RGBA_8888.
03-24 00:49:10.693: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d4cb000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:57
03-24 00:49:10.713: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d8f7000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:68
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5e14e000 size:614400 offset:0 fd:72
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5ca41000 size:614400
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dc22000 size:614400
03-24 00:49:10.753: D/memalloc(6809): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x5dcb8000 size:614400
```

P.S.

Thank you Everyone!

Comment: Post the logcat, it will contain the reason for the FC.

Comment: Done : ) [its posted above]

Comment: The FC is due to a null pointer exception in line 99 of your class in the saveContact number. What line is this? Maybe you need a null check there.

Comment: I know how to fix it... just remove the new line of code I added. 

(Check out the updated description above)

Comment: You don't need to get data out of the extras more than once as you have the items created as fields and you're handling that part in onCreate().  You need to null check a lot of things in your code.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're getting "time" + "min" which is actually "timemin", but in the second example you're getting "time".

So, a couple of things ...

```
public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_TIME = "time";
public static final String KEY_BUNDLE_MIN = "min";
```

From the class that calls the putExtra use AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME for the key in your key-value pair.  Same for AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN.  This lets the activity/fragment being called control the entries passed in the bundle and ensures you don't create typos, etc.

Also, you can check to make sure the key exists before performing the get ...

```
if (extras.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) {
    timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME));
} else {
    timeEt.setCurrentHour(0);
}
```

OR

```
timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.containsKey(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) ? extras.getInt(KEY_BUNDLE_TIME) : 0);
```

Comment: Find your "puts" extras.putInt(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_TIME, yourTimeValueInt) and extras.putInt(AddEditCountry.KEY_BUNDLE_MIN, yourMinValueInt).  Then just make the changes I outlined in my answer.

Comment: Ok - I did both - but it's force closing on me (I've updated my source above with my latest AddEditCountries.java, DatabaseConnector.java and a LOGCAT (it force closes when I attempted to run your suggested source code [I did clean it though and it comes back clean]

Comment: ...and thank you for your help - it is much needed AND appreciated

Comment: I still really need help with this... can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The single change between your two code snippets is the line that makes your app crash. But, that changed line of code is not the same as you reported in the beginning part of your question.

**Old Non-Force Close**:

```
timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time"));
```

**New Force Close**:

```
timeEt.setCurrentHour(extras.getInt("time" + ("min")));
```

The Force Close is being caused by "`extras.getInt("timemin")));`", which probably returns `null`. Therefore, "`timeEt.setCurrentHour(null);`" causes a `NullPointerException`.

**Your post**, on the other hand, indicates that you added this line of code:

```
timeEt.setText(extras.getString("time") + ":" + extras.getString("min"));
```

Make your new code match your post and your crash should be fixed.

Comment: Apologies - I was trying a few things to get it back working again and the line  timeEt.setText(extras.getString("time") + ":" + extras.getString("min")); was suggested to me as a way to combine currentHour and currentMinute into a single string  (which I'm still unable to do - but hopefully will be able to soon! Thanks to awesome StackOverflow members such as yourself) and I had it copied in a notepad - I apologize for the [major] typo!

Comment: BTW can you take another look at this? I'm still stuck trying to concatonate the two variables... its force closing but I've included a logcat, the source (after updating it with the user Bill Mote's suggestions) but I'm still stuck - with no final answer

Comment: The NullPointerException occurs on line 65 of AddEditCountry.java in the function doInBackground(). A NullPointerException indicates that you are evaluating a variable that is null, which is both the most common way to force close an application and usually the easiest to fix. Is your current code still PasteBoarded? Of, can you point us to that line of code?

Comment: Line 65 is  saveContact(); 



...and yes the currently published code (AddEditCountry and Database Connector) and the logcat are my current code still. : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for getting time

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int min= c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int hour= c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
String time=hour+":"+min+":"+seconds;
```

Comment: I dont need the time... I need to create a time value from the TimePicker's currentHour and currentMinute 

(My goal is to create buttons that changed a stored time string in another XML layout so the user can save a time preference)